# How to create HTML search function to narrow results in a table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, search

We are trying to create a search function that when a user starts typing in a name the results shown in a table below are shortened i.e the table originally contains the names Bob, Carl, Harry, Paul, Harriet. The user starts typing B in and the table below just shows Bob (not the other four names). If  the user types Harr both Harry and Harriet would show in the table below.

However for added functionality If the user types in Hary (instead of Harry) the table below will still show Harry (as it is assumed that is what is being spelt).

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?

$sql = "SELECT name, region FROM jos_users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 6";

$rsd = mysql_query($sql, $dbconn);
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
    $name = $rs['name'];        
    $region = $rs['region'];        


     ?>

            <tr>
                <td><?php 
                echo $name; 
                ?></td>
                <td><?php 
                echo $region; 
                ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
} 
?>              

        </table>
```

Comment: Please supply some code .

Comment: At the moment we haven't got a great deal of code to show

Comment: Each name in a separate row, or all in a single row? Elaborate on the table.

Comment: @MikeyBarker ,then show us Less code u tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use datatables for this functionality

Integrate your table with below code

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://socialleadchief.com/src/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="http://socialleadchief.com/src/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="http://socialleadchief.com/src/css/dataTables.bootstrap.css"></script>
    <script src="http://socialleadchief.com/src/css/tooltip.css"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $("#example1").dataTable();
            $('#example2').dataTable({
                //"bJQueryUI": true,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                // "bScrollCollapse": true,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bSort": true,
                "bInfo": true,
                "bAutoWidth": false
            });
        });
    </script>

<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>    
            <th>column 1</th>
            <th>column 2</th>
            <th>column 3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>data 1</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
            <td>data 3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

It will give you sorting functionaity also.

Comment: save the css and js files from socialleadchief.com in your local folder through view page option,because your table will not work if server of that website is down.